# Connect to Database Engine Prompt on Script Object

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

Every time I right-click an object in SSMS 2016 and click **Script Object As** > **CREATE To** > **New Query Editor Window**, I get the prompt below. Not sure if I changed a setting or what, but was hoping someone knew how to make it so it doesn't prompt to open a new connection each time.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried getting all of the way out of SSMS and coming back in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem you're encountering.

Originally, I wasn't being prompted like you are being prompted.  There is a button just to the right of New Query that invokes the Database Engine Query.  This button would be very easy to click because it's close the the New Query button

[image]

This brings up the connection dialog box you are experiencing.  The problem is, once you click this button, you will continually be prompted for a connection until you exit out of SSMS and come back in (at least, that is how I corrected the problem).